# Problems with receiving in the mailbox with postfix

Tags: email, postfix

I installed the Postfix MTA, I configured it to work as "internet site" and I added the corresponding domain name to the mail system to be able to receive the mails. However, the problem I am having is that in the syslog it says that the mail has been sent successfully, but in my mail inbox, in this case, I am using Gmail, the mail has not arrived.